# How to convert a CustomBindingElement to a Binding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I want to instantiate programmatically a WCF client. The client requires a `Binding` and an `EndpointAddress`. I have  a configuration file which I have opened using `OpenExeConfig` and have retrieved the relevant binding from `cfg.GetSection("system.serviceModel/bindings")[1]`.

However, instead of a `Binding`, I get a `CustomBindingElement`.

My question is - how do I programmatically convert a `CustomBindingElement` into a `Binding` so it can be consumed by my client?